# What variables are set in a Jquery Ajax call and how can I see the data before it is sent?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a question re the ajax data - Do I need to set a variable to each value I want to pass? - in this case it will be the value that has been inputted into the input box.  Also were abouts can I output `console.log(data)` to see whats in the ajax data array?

**Function:**

```
function urlCheck() {

    $(".postForm").on('click', '#post_title', function (e) {

        var id = $('#post_title').data("id");

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?=base_url()?>/page/op',
            data: {
                post_title: $("#post_title").val(),
                    'website_id': id
            },

            type: 'POST',
            success: function (resp) {
                alert(resp);
            },
            error: function (resp) {
                console.log("Error in ajax request");
            }
        });

    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the data array create it first:

```
var data = {
    param1 : "foo",
    param2 : "bar"
};
console.log(data);
```

The use it in your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
   //...
   data:data
   //...
});
```

If you don't add a variable then it isn't passed so if you have to have it, just set it to an empty string.